After update from ubuntu 24.04 to 24.10 dark mode stops working
After updating from 24.04 to 24.10 I got this message and dark mode stopped working
Error found by loading the /etc/profile:

run-parts:failed to stat component /etc/profile.d/debuginfod.sh: No such file or directory

and my solution was to run this command
sudo apt install libdebuginfod-dev

Do you still have a question ? Is the dark mode related to sudo apt install libdebuginfod-dev?
